# Using CPAN to install Dancer and dependencies

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan, dancer

I am trying to create a sample web service using Dancer. I am using Ubuntu 10.04 as my OS. I installed Dancer and dependencies using CPAN client and can also do

```
dancer -a MyApp
```

However, when I try to run the app.pl file, the code throws an error saying YAML.pm not found. I am sure this file was downloaded when the dependencies were installed. A have a few questions :-

```
1. Where does CPAN put all these files which were downloaded? How are they included in the @INC?
2. For using Dancer, do I have to manually include all the files in @INC?
```

I tried to create  a very simple perl dancer app the says hello world by including the Dancer.pm path in @INC. However, it keeps failing because of some or the other dependency missing.

Help me in understanding what am I doing wrong?

Comment: See also this [rejected bug](https://github.com/PerlDancer/Dancer/issues/502) in Dancer's issue tracker on GitHub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cpan should put files in one of the path from @INC
`perl -E '$"="\n"; say "@INC"'`
Output on my system:

```
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2
/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2
/usr/lib/perl5
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/perl/5.14
/usr/share/perl/5.14
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
.
```

And cpan puts files in /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2
Because this path exists in @INC you shouldn't include it manually. And what about Dancer, YAML is not hard dependency for it, because of this it wasn't installed.

Comment: Accepting the answer. This is what I was looking for. Also when I say use Dancer':syntax', I see no errors thrown. Any explanation why?

Comment: Because Dancer.pm doesn't requires YAML itself. Only several submodules requires YAML: Dancer::Session::YAML, Dancer::Config, Dancer::Serializer::YAML. And I think this submodules will not load when you say use Dancer':syntax'